# Wpf UI does not update

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mvvm, command

I have a wpf mvvm application.
There is a button in the view and it is bound to a command in the view model.
The function CanExecute of this command returns the value of some bool property

```
private bool Command1CanExecute()
{
    return IsConnected;
}
```

When the property is changed, the button should become disabled but it's doesn't happened until I click somewhere in UI.
The solution I have thought about (and it works :) ) is to run

```
  CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

each second (Dispatcher timer can do it).

Is there another, more elegant solution for my problem?
Thank you.

Matvey.

Comment: Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your Command class? (Or whatever the equivalent is for the "CanExecute" stuff in Commands...I'm too new to WPF to know exactly what I mean :) )

Comment: Reading the docs, it looks like you're supposed to implement the method "CanExecute" (not "Command1CanExecute) as well as the event "CanExecuteChanged".

Comment: @PeterDuniho There is nothing wrong with code that op has posted. The canExecute takes a predicate and the implementation here is as expected.

Comment: @Matvey can you post the code for IsConnected please?

Comment: @Krishna: thanks for the clarification. The OP didn't post any context, so it's hard to tell what he's actually defining here (I thought an ICommand implementation was a safe guess, but apparently not). Maybe he or you could expound a bit on what "CanExecute" takes a predicate, and why a method named "Command1CanExecute" serves the purpose here? Is the assumption here that he is implementing a DelegateCommand<T> subclass?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry I have been working on Prism lately and when I saw CanExecute I thought it was a RelayCommand Implementation with a CanExecute Predicate. I might have got it wrong

Answer (score 3):

All Commands are updated after any userinteraction. If you change a property programmatically and want to update the command-states you have to suggest a requery after your property has changed:

```
CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
```

you can also raise a CanExecuteChanged-Event of your command (which simply does nothing else than above)

```
Command1.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

you'd insert any of this in the setter of `IsConnected` like following

```
private bool _isConnected;
public bool IsConnected
{
  get { return _isConnected; }
  set
  {
    if (_isConnected != value)
    { 
      _isConnected = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(); //or something similar
      Command1.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

if you don't want that,
you can just return `true` in your CanExecute-Handler and bind `IsEnabled` of your button to the property itself.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsConnected}" Command="{Binding Command1}" ... />
```

Comment: Correct, except that depending on the `ICommand` implementation being used, there might not be a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method. `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` is the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: you're right, it depends on the mvvm framework which is used. Though its implementation would propably just call the `CommandManager` itself.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque: sorry for butting in with my confused self, but...why would the lack of a RaiseCanExecuteChanged() method necessarily lead to calling CommandManager's method? ICommand has a CanExecuteChanged event...why wouldn't an implementer just go ahead and raise the event itself?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, `ICommand` implementations are supposed to raise their `CanExecuteChanged` event when the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event is raised. That event is raised regularly by WPF, and also when you call `InvalidateRequerySuggested()`. Some `ICommand` implementations have a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method to raise the event explicitly, but they don't have to, since it's not part of the interface. So without knowing which implementation the OP is using, we don't know if the method exists; the alternative is to call `InvalidateRequerySuggested` directly to trigger the event.

Comment: Just in case if you use Telerik, you need to call `myCommand.InvalidateCanExecute()`.

Answer (score -1):

For those who uses MicroMvvm the change needs to be applied to the class:    `public class RelayCommand<T>:ICommand`

and method:

```
 [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public Boolean CanExecute(Object parameter)
        {

            var valu = _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            return valu;
        }
```